# Fluent API Composite Foreign Key with Generic Object Type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, fluent-interface

I have an Organization class and a User class as follows, & I want to be able to assign an Address to each individually - without having the need for two separate many-to-many tables for AddressUser & AddressOrganization, AddressAnything, etc.  The reason being is I may have multiple entities that I want to assign an Address to & don't want an in-between join table for every single entity that needs an Address record.

I also don't want to store a foreign keys like Address.OrganizationId or Address.UserId for each entity that needs an address associated with it.

Is there a way Fluent API or Code-First Data Annotations can accommodate some sort of composite generic foreign key with an object type?

Like a DomainObjectType table?

**DomainObjectType:**

```cs
public class DomainObjectType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } // seeded

    public string ObjectType { get; set; } // User or Organization
}
```

DomainObjectType would be seeded with:

```cs
var objTypes = new List<DomainObjectType>
  { 
      new DomainObjectType() { Id = 1, ObjectType = "User" },
      new DomainObjectType() { Id = 2, ObjectType = "Organization" }
  };
objTypes.ForEach(c => context.DomainObjectTypes.Add(c));
context.SaveChanges();
```

**Organization:**

```cs
public class Organization
    {    
        // Primary key
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        #region Navigation Properties

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

        #endregion

    }
```

**User**

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

**Address**

```cs
public class Address
{
    // Primary Key
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string AddressType { get; set; }

    #region Foreign Keys

    // not completely sure about this? (maybe move to many-to-many "join" table)
    public int DomainObjectId { get; set; } // Composite key; would be either an OrganizationId or UserId
    public string DomainObjectTypeId { get; set; } // Composite key

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual ICollection<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    #endregion

}
```

**Fluent API stuff:**

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Code First to ignore PluralizingTableName convention
        // If you keep this convention then the generated tables will have pluralized names.
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        // one-to-many Organization-to-Users
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.Organization)
            .WithMany(o => o.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.OrganizationId);

        // what goes here for generic AddressDomainObjectType?
    }
```

Comment: Do you have many-to-many relationships between `Address` and `User` and between `Address` and `Organization`? You say so at the beginning, but your model sketch does not look like many-to-many.

Comment: Your model is confusing as @Slauma said - but you may just need the following `.HasForeignKey(i => new { i.DomainObjectId, i.DomainObjectTypeId })` for your `Address` table, I'm guessing.

Comment: Corrected my User & Address class to indicate many-to-many.  It looks like I may need a many-to-many after all - AddressDomainObjectType?

Comment: I think I was trying to put everything I needed in the Address table like what NSGaga is suggesting, but after reviewing my model as you guys indicated, I don't want multiple many-to-many tables (i.e. AddressUser or AddressOrganization or AddressAnything).  I want one many-to-many table that has a DomainObjectTypeId included in its composite foreign key.  Just not sure how to express that in Fluent API or my Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want - having only a single many-to-many table between `Address` and "other entities" - by creating a base class for those "other entities", for example:

```
public abstract class DomainObjectWithAddresses
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class User : DomainObjectWithAddresses
{
    // other properties but without Id which is inherited from base class
}

public class Organization : DomainObjectWithAddresses
{    
    // other properties but without Id which is inherited from base class
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // other properties

    public virtual ICollection<DomainObjectWithAddresses> DomainObjects
                                                                 { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DomainObjectWithAddresses>()
    .HasMany(d => d.Addresses)
    .WithMany(a => a.DomainObjects)
    .Map(x =>
    {
        x.ToTable("DomainObjectAddresses");
        x.MapLeftKey("DomainObjectId");
        x.MapRightKey("AddressId");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .ToTable("Users");           // TPT inheritance mapping

modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>()
    .ToTable("Organizations");   // TPT inheritance mapping
```

Your `DbContext` has a `DbSet` for the base type:

```
public DbSet<DomainObjectWithAddresses> DomainObjects { get; set; }
```

I don't like it. I would prefer to introduce multiple join tables for every type that has a many-to-many relationship with addresses. I have doubt that it is a good idea to introduce an abstraction in the domain model only for the sake of saving a few tables in the database. This abstract `DomainObjectWithAddresses` class is a very technical ("table-savings-helper") artifact that has no valuable meaning in your domain model. For me it sounds much more natural to say that a user **has** addresses and an organization **has** addresses instead of saying that a user **is** an object with addresses and an organization **is** an object with addresses. On the long run this will only complicate working with your model.

Comment: You solved my problem, but steered me in the other direction - wow, thank you for the honest observation.  I agree that it does start to feel like I'm over complicating things here even though I could technically achieve it.  I'll accept your answer, but go with the extra multiple join tables.

Comment: I was trying to do the same base-class for my entities (with the additional complexity that I working with an existing database), and then I realized that a much more natural design would be splitting the Address type into subtypes like UserAddress and OrganizationAddress. See my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275335/polymorphic-associations-in-entity-framework/38287144#38287144
(I know this question is old, but it can someone else)